# Can't start Apache in chroot with systemctl but can run it manually on my own from Bash with no issue

Tags: apache-http-server, chroot, systemctl

How to keep my Apache webserver running (prevent from being killed off for some unknown reason) in `chroot` when launched with `systemctl` at boot?

My setup requires multiple scripts and when I start the main script `gjaw.sh` on my own (When I execute `bash gjaw.sh`), Apache doesn't get killed.

Here are the scripts that are used for webserver startup:

- Main systemctl service file (`gjaw.service`)
- Main script (`gjaw.sh`)
- Sub-script (`chroot` environment starter) (`.chroot.sh`)
- Sub-script (`rsync` / `ftp` bind mount directories) (`bindfs.sh`)
- `journalctl` log for main service file (`gjaw-service.log`)
- Apache error log (`error_log`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by backing up all my web root files and moving it to a new LAMP Stack server.